# Why does Firefox plugin check report Shockwave Flash as outdated?

Tags: linux, debian, firefox-extensions, adobe-flash

I have a Debian x86_64 system with Firefox installed from Mozilla's tar.gz.

On the addons page (hit CONTROL+SHIFT+A then go to the Plugins tab) there is a link: "[Check to see if your plugins are up to date.](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/)"
When I click on it displays: Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202 vulnerable.
When I click on "[Update now](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)" the version presented to me to download is:

```
Adobe Flash Player version 11.2.202.291
Your system: Linux 64-bit, Firefox
```

Which is the same I already have.

### Additional information

The version string in Add-ons Manager's Plugin tab is: Shockwave Flash 11,2,202,291

```
# /usr/sbin/update-flashplugin-nonfree --status
Flash Player version installed on this system  : 11.2.202.291
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 11.2.202.291
flash-mozilla.so - auto mode   
  link currently points to /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so - priority 50
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so'.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because 11.2 is the last supported version for Firefox on Linux. Flash is up to version 11.7.something on chrome and other OSes.

See here: http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/